# Not able to insert data into ArrayField while using psqlextra.backend with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-migrations

I have a model with an ArrayField, having JSONField as base. When I try to insert data, it gives the following error:

```
ProgrammingError: column "data" is of type jsonb[] but expression is of type text[]
LINE 1: ...e_status_code", "is_success", "error") VALUES (1, ARRAY['"a"...
                                                             ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

I am using psqlextra.backend as my default database engine. My model and other relevant codes are:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField, ArrayField

class TestModel(models.Model):
    data = ArrayField(
        JSONField(),
        blank=True,
        )
```

My corresponding migration file looks like this:

```
import django.contrib.postgres.fields
import django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('emails', '0003_auto_20200408_1351'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='TestModel',
            name='data',
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='TestModel',
            name='data',
            field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.ArrayField(base_field=django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(), blank=True, size=None),
        ),
    ]
```

I tried adding data like this:

```
TestModel.objects.create(
    data= [{"a":"b"}, {"c":"d"}]
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further digging up, this was a known bug in Django<2.2

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28291

Upgrading django did the job!